# Converted website into an app but the pop window is not opening

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not a coder. But I have converted my already-well-built website into an Android app.

The problem is: a Popup window doesn't open in my app.
It opens in the desktop version and it also opens perfectly in mobile browsers.
In my app, it simply stays on the same page.

What to do?

Answer (score -1):

In android You need to design `.xml` files and Develop `.class` files accordingly .

if you cannot do it yourself Ask someone to do it for you..

You can not just use webview and expect it will work in proper manner.